# Limiting available choices in a Django formset

Tags: django

I have a formset which has a field "Teams" which should be limited to the teams the current user belongs to.

```
def edit_scrapbook(request):
    u=request.user
    ScrapbookAjaxForm = modelformset_factory(Scrapbook, fields=
          ('description','status','team'))
    choices=False
    for t in u.team_set.all():
        if choices:
            choices=choices,(t.id,t.name)
        else:
            choices=choices,(t.id,t.name)
   if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ScrapbookAjaxForm(request.POST, 
            queryset=Scrapbook.objects.filter(owner=u))
        if formset.is_valid():
            instances=formset.save(commit=False)
            for i in instances:
                i.owner=request.user
                i.save()
            formset.save_m2m()    
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('scrapbooks.views.index'))
    else:
        formset = ScrapbookAjaxForm(queryset=Scrapbook.objects.filter(owner=u))
        for form in forms:
            for field in form:
                if field.label == 'Team':
                    field.choices=choices
    c=RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('scrapbooks/ajax_edit.html', 
             {'fs':formset},context_instance=c)
```

This does not seem to affect the choices in the form at all.  This is quite ugly and probably the result of looking at this problem for way too long.  I have also tried using a custom formset but I can't seem to get the custom formset to accept the parameter.

How do I limit the choices for the Team field on my subselect in a formset based on the teams the user is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [django model documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices):

> Finally, note that choices can be any
>   iterable object -- not necessarily a
>   list or tuple. This lets you construct
>   choices dynamically. But if you find
>   yourself hacking choices to be
>   dynamic, you're probably better off
>   using a proper database table with a
>   ForeignKey. choices is meant for
>   static data that doesn't change much,
>   if ever.

I would use then the same idea: in the form, you use a ForeignKey for the team and then, you can limit that list with some query.

Some further suggestion:

- Use a ForeignKey for the team
- [Define your own ModelChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), with a query that will limit its content, basing on a parameter given in its initialization.
- [Override the default field type](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types), to use your own ModelChoiceField. Note that you should pass the filter for the team in the initialization of your ModelChoiceField.

Comment: How do I send the list of iterable objects to the formset?  This is where I'm having trouble, I can't seem to get any settings I make in the view to stick in the formset.

Comment: Ok, I've added a possible way to set the list of iterables.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause of the issue, but there's a big problem with the way you build up the choices tuple.

After four teams, choices will look like this:

```
((((False, (1, u'Team 1')), (2L, u'Team 2')), (3, u'Team 3')), (4, u'Team 4'))
```

which obviously isn't valid for setting a choice field.  A much better way of doing it would be to use a list comprehension in place of the whole loop:

```
choices = [(t.id,t.name) for t in u.team_set.all()]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not used to working with lists in Python yet, that's a much cleaner method and as you say generates the correct result.  Unfortunately does not solve my issue.